# Is it better to define Functor in terms of Applicative in terms of Monad, or vice versa?

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, applicative

This is a general question, not tied to any one piece of code.

Say you have a type `T a` that can be given an instance of `Monad`. Since every monad is an `Applicative` by assigning `pure = return` and `(<*>) = ap`, and then every applicative is a `Functor` via `fmap f x = pure f <*> x`, is it better to define your instance of `Monad` first, and then trivially give `T` instances of `Applicative` and `Functor`?

It feels a bit backward to me. If I were doing math instead of programming, I would think that I would first show that my object is a functor, and then continue adding restrictions until I have also shown it to be a monad. I know Haskell is merely inspired by Category Theory and obviously the techniques one would use when constructing a proof aren't the techniques one would use when writing a useful program, but I'd like to get an opinion from the Haskell community. Is it better to go from `Monad` down to `Functor`? or from `Functor` up to `Monad`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I tend to write and see written the `Functor` instance first. Doubly so because if you use the `LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor` pragma then `data Foo a = Foo a deriving ( Functor )` works most of the time.

The tricky bits are around agreement of instances when your `Applicative` can be more general than your `Monad`. For instance, here's an `Err` data type

```
data Err e a = Err [e] | Ok a deriving ( Functor )

instance Applicative (Err e) where
  pure = Ok
  Err es <*> Err es' = Err (es ++ es')
  Err es <*> _       = Err es
  _      <*> Err es  = Err es
  Ok  f  <*> Ok  x   = Ok (f x)

instance Monad (Err e) where
  return = pure
  Err es >>= _ = Err es
  Ok  a  >>= f = f a
```

Above I defined the instances in `Functor`-to-`Monad` order and, taken in isolation, each instance is correct. Unfortunately, the `Applicative` and `Monad` instances do not align: `ap` and `(<*>)` are observably different as are `(>>)` and `(*>)`.

```
Err "hi" <*>  Err "bye" == Err "hibye"
Err "hi" `ap` Err "bye" == Err "hi"
```

For sensibility purposes, especially once the Applicative/Monad Proposal is in everyone's hands, these should align. If you defined `instance Applicative (Err e) where { pure = return; (<*>) = ap }` then they *will* align.

But then, finally, you may be capable of carefully teasing apart the differences in `Applicative` and `Monad` so that they behave differently in benign ways---such as having a lazier or more efficient `Applicative` instance. This actually occurs fairly frequently and I feel the jury is still a little bit out on what "benign" means and under what kinds of "observation" should your instances align. Perhaps some of the most gregarious use of this is in the Haxl project at Facebook where the `Applicative` instance is *more parallelized* than the `Monad` instance, and thus is far more efficient at the cost of some fairly severe "unobserved" side effects.

In any case, if they differ, document it.

Answer (score 6):

I often choose a reverse approach as compared to the one in Abrahamson's answer. I manually define only the `Monad` instance and define the `Applicative` and `Functor` in terms of it with the help of already defined functions in the `Control.Monad`, which renders those instances the same for absolutely any monad, i.e.:

```
instance Applicative SomeMonad where
  pure = return
  (<*>) = ap

instance Functore SomeMonad where
  fmap = liftM
```

While this way the definition of `Functor` and `Applicative` is always "brain-free" and very easy to reason about, I must note that this is not the ultimate solution, since there are cases, when the instances can be implemented more efficiently or even provide new features. E.g., the `Applicative` instance of [`Concurrently`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.0.2/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:Concurrently) executes things ... concurrently, while the `Monad` instance can only execute them sequentially due to the nature of monads.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not say this is a bad way. I'm just highlighting the benefits and drawbacks of the `F->A->M` method. I personally tend to define whichever of function is easiest to get right, in order.

Comment: I think E.Kmett said in the haskellcast that there will be a change such that `Monad` will a subclass of `Applicative`, but I don't know exactly when this change will happen.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: that's pretty irrelevant; subclassing has nothing to do with dependencies between the instance definitions.

Comment: The only issue with this is that sometimes these are less efficient than hand-written versions.  The list monad is a good example, where `liftM` would be less efficient than a hand-written `map` without rewrite rules.

Answer (score 3):

`Functor` instances are typically very simple to define, I'd normally do those by hand.

For `Applicative` and `Monad`, it depends. `pure` and `return` are usually similarly easy, and it really doesn't matter in which class you put the expanded definition. For bind, it is sometimes benfitial to go the "category way", i.e. define a specialised `join' :: (M (M x)) -> M x` first and then `a>>=b = join' $ fmap b a` (which of course wouldn't work if you had defined `fmap` in terms of `>>=`). Then it's probably useful to just re-use `(>>=)` for the `Applicative` instance.

Other times, the `Applicative` instance can be written quite easily [or is more efficient than the generic Monad-derived implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590639/examples-of-a-monad-whose-applicative-part-can-be-better-optimized-than-the-mona/18592203#18592203). In that case, you should definitely define `<*>` separately.

Answer (score 0):

The magic here, that the Haskell uses the Kleisli-tiplet notation of a monad, that
is more convenient way, if somebody wants to use monads in imperative programming like tools.

I asked the same question, and the answer come after a while, if you see the definitions
of the **Functor**, **Applicative**, **Monad** in haskell you miss one link, which is the original definition of the monad, which contains only the *join* operation, that can be found on the [HaskellWiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad).

With this point of view you will see how haskell monads are built up functor, applicative functors, monads and Kliesli triplet.

A rough explanation can be found here: https://github.com/andorp/pearls/blob/master/Monad.hs
And other with the same ideas here: http://people.inf.elte.hu/pgj/haskell2/jegyzet/08/Monad.hs

Answer (score 0):

I think you mis-understand how sub-classes work in Haskell.  They aren't like OO sub-classes!  Instead, a sub-class constraint, like

```
class Applicative m => Monad m
```

says "any type with a canonical `Monad` structure must also have a canonical `Applicative` structure".  There are two basic reasons why you would place a constraint like that:

- The sub-class structure *induces* a super-class structure.
- The super-class structure is a natural subset of the sub-class structure.

For example, consider:

```
class Vector v where
    (.^) :: Double -> v -> v
    (+^) :: v -> v -> v
    negateV :: v -> v

class Metric a where
    distance :: a -> a -> Double

class (Vector v, Metric v) => Norm v where
    norm :: v -> Double
```

The first super-class constraint on `Norm` arises because the concept of a normed space is really weak unless you also assume a vector space structure; the second arises because (given a vector space) a `Norm` induces a `Metric`, which you can prove by observing that

```
instance Metric V where
    distance v0 v1 = norm (v0 .^ negateV v1)
```

is a valid `Metric` instance for *any* `V` with a valid `Vector` instance and a valid `norm` function.  We say that the norm *induces* a metric.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space#Topological_structure .

The `Functor` and `Applicative` super-classes on `Monad` are like `Metric`, not like `Vector`: the `return` and `>>=` functions from `Monad` induce `Functor` and `Applicative` structures:

- `fmap`: can be defined as `fmap f a = a >>= return . f`, which was `liftM` in the Haskell 98 standard library.
- `pure`: is the same operation as `return`; the two names is a legacy from when `Applicative` wasn't a super-class of `Monad`.
- `<*>`: can be defined as `af <*> ax = af >>= \ f -> ax >>= \ x -> return (f x)`, which was `liftM2 ($)` in the Haskell 98 standard library.
- `join`: can be defined as `join aa = aa >>= id`.

So it's perfectly sensible, mathematically, to define the `Functor` and `Applicative` operations in terms of `Monad`.