# Haskell - can you have a monad that is not an applicative functor?

Tags: haskell, monads, fam-proposal

In [this set of slides by Jim Duey at slide 13](http://www.clojure.net/assets/ClojureWest13/abstractions.svg#%7Bstep%2013%7D) - he suggests that all Monads are applicative functors.

[image]

In the Haskell 7.7 compiler output - I'm seeing the following (another example [is here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.ghc.devel/2397)):

> ‛Parser’ is an instance of Monad but not Applicative - this will become an error in GHC 7.10, under the Applicative-Monad Proposal.

Does this mean the Haskell Compiler currently tolerates Monads that are not applicative functors - but the plan is to correct this?

Comment: All `Monad`s *can be made* an instance of `Applicative`, but not all of them necessarily have been (at least not by GHC 7.6).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right now `Applicative` isn't a superclass of `Monad`

```
instance Monad m where ...      -- this is how it is today, instead of
instance Applicative m => Monad m where ...
```

but it is planned so that in GHC 7.10 this will be changed so that `Applicative` *is* a superclass of `Monad`. In order to help the transition, in GHC 7.7 and 7.8 there will be the warning you saw issued whenever GHC encounters a `Monad` without an `Applicative` instance.

---

Now the slightly confusing bit is that *all* valid `Monad`s are applicative functors, even if they're not `instance`s of `Applicative`. We can write

```
fmapM :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
fmapM f ma = ma >>= return . f                      -- a.k.a. `liftM`

pureM :: Monad m => a -> m a
pureM = return

ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
ap mf ma = do { f <- mf; a <- ma; return (f a) }    -- a.k.a. `ap`
```

which together satisfy the signature and laws of `Functor` and `Applicative`. This is why the superclass constraint makes sense to add and it's purely historical accident that it wasn't there in the first case—`Applicative`s were discovered and popularized far after `Monad`s were.

```
newtype WrappedMonad m a = WM (m a)

instance Monad m => Functor (WrappedMonad m) where
  fmap f (WM m) = WM (liftM f m)

instance Monad m => Applicative (WrappedMonad m) where
  pure = WM . return
  WM mf <*> WM ma = WM $ mf `ap` ma
```

For more information on how `Applicative` and `Monad` relate, take a look at an answer I wrote previously here: [Is it better to define Functor in terms of Applicative in terms of Monad, or vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635265/is-it-better-to-define-functor-in-terms-of-applicative-in-terms-of-monad-or-vic/19635558#19635558)

Comment: Another way to say this might be: "all monads are applicative functors (mathematically speaking), but not all `Monad`s are `Applicative`s (Haskellically speaking and in GHC ≤7.8)."

Comment: What will change in the code? Does it mean that for each monad we will have to add the definitions of `fmap`, `pure`, `<*>` or will they be added somehow automatically, since for a monad they always have the same definition in terms of `return` and `>>=`?

Comment: We'll have `class Applicative m => Monad m` so that in order to declare `instance Monad m` you must first declare `instance Applicative m`. For most monads the applicative instance can be cheaply instantiated as `instance Applicative m where { pure = return; (<*>) = ap }`.